# Terrible performance of this code

Tags: php, mysql, performance, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter and mysql and i am trying to get some data from mssql server and updating to my system. Its very slow. please let me know if anything wrong i am doing..

```
class systemupdate extends MY_Controller{

    function systemupdate() {      
        return parent::MY_Controller();
    }

    function index(){
        $message = '';                                                                                   
        $message = "CRON Information::COMMON INVENTORY SYSTEM: QUANTITY UPDATE FOR TRADE WH STARTED.";
        log_message('info', $message);  
        $this->load->model("cis/sapinventorymodel");
        $objMainResult = $this->sapinventorymodel->FetchDetailsByUnit(420);
        $mainResult = json_decode($objMainResult);
        if((isset($mainResult)) && ($mainResult->results > 0))  
        {
            $this->load->model("cron/systemupdatemodel");
            foreach($mainResult->rows as $main)
            {
                $arrQuantity = '';
                $arrQuantity = $this->systemupdatemodel->FetchTradeWhQuantity($main->number);
                if((isset($arrQuantity)) && (count($arrQuantity) > 0))
                {
                    if((isset($arrQuantity[0]->quantity)) && ($arrQuantity[0]->quantity != NULL)){
                        $objMainResult = $this->sapinventorymodel->SaveTradeWhQuantity($main->a_umber, $main->a_plant,
                                                                                     $main->a_unit,$arrQuantity[0]->quantity);
                    }
                }   
            }
        }
        $message = "CRON Information::COMMON INVENTORY SYSTEM: QUANTITY UPDATE FOR TRADE WH FINSIHED.";
        log_message('info', $message);      
    }   
}
```

Here is the model

```
class systemupdatemodel extends MY_Model {

    function systemupdatemodel() {
        parent::__construct();
        $CI->sapData    =   $this->load->database("sapinventory", TRUE);
        $this->sapData  =   &$CI->sapData;
    }

    function FetchTradeWhQuantity($p_intNumber){

        $query = $this->sapData->query("SELECT quantity FROM master1 WHERE NUMBER = '$p_intNumber'");
            if(($query->num_rows() > 0) && ($query->num_rows() == 1)){
                return $query->result();
            }else
            {
                $query1 = $this->sapData->query("SELECT  quantity FROM master2 WHERE EANNUMBER = '$p_intNumber'");
                if(($query1->num_rows() > 0) && ($query1->num_rows() == 1)){
                    return $query1->result();
                }                   
            }                                       
    }
}
```

Total number of records are 7857 i.e this many times its in loop. **sapinventory** is a mssql server.

Comment: One thing you can improve is to simplify `($query->num_rows() > 0) && ($query->num_rows() == 1)` to `($query->num_rows() == 1)`. This will reduce the number of `$query->num_rows()` calls. When the result is `1` it's always larger than `0`.

Comment: How terrible is the performance? How long does it take to execute? Your doing 2 database queries for each row of data you pulled from your first query. So thats potentially around 15,000 calls to the db.

Comment: @Jeemusu - Its supposed to be a CRON job. It checks 1st table and if its not there then it checks second table for data. Its taking more then 10 mins.

Comment: 10 mins doesn't sound too bad. Has it always taken that long to run, or has it been gradually increasing?

Comment: @Jeemusu  - sorry for the mistake.  It takes more then 30-40mins..sometimes it just keeps on running.

Comment: Take a look at how to profile your CI app: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/profiling.html

Comment: If its a database table you've been using for a long time, and that has lots of records deleted/added/updated constantly, the table may just need optimizing.

Comment: Are NUMBER and EANNUMBER indexed?

Comment: @GordonM - That is MSSql server and its not in our control.

Comment: @Hacker It's still a worthwhile question. If you can't answer it yourself, then ask whoever can.  I'm assuming you can at least talk to whoever is in control of the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FetchTradeWhQuantity` and `SaveTradeWhQuantity` does a lot of runs in this case. That means (probably) at least 3 mysql queries per row. If you'd consider running this through 1 or 2 big queries instead, your performance would go up very noticeable.

Now this might be something easy to do, or something hard to do.

For instance;

```
function FetchTradeWhQuantity($p_intNumber){ ... }
```

Could be

```
function FetchTradeWhQuantity($p_intNumber) {

    $query = $this->sapData->query("

                           SELECT quantity
                           FROM master 1
                           WHERE NUMBER = '{$p_intNumber}'
                           UNION
                           SELECT quantity
                           FROM master2
                           WHERE EANNUMBER = '{$p_intNumber}'

                                   ");

    if ($query->num_rows() == 1)
        return $query->result();

}
```

But the **best** thing you can do is to do all of this with 2-3 queries *only*. Fetch all data, use their IDs and run a `UPDATE` or `INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`. Then the server only have to connect to the mysql database a few times and doesn't have to play pinball with the php for each little row.